# How to apply 1/σ^2 weight matrix to find Weighted Least Squares Solution

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, least-squares

I am trying to solve a Weighted Least Squares problem on Python (using numpy) but I am unsure on how to apply the following weight

[image]

on [image]

This is what i have done so far

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(50) #Generate X values 
Y = 2 + 3*X + np.random.rand(50) #Y Values
plt.plot(X,Y,'o')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
W = ?? 
X_b = np.c_[np.ones((50,1)), X] #generate [1,x]
beta = np.linalg.inv(X_b.T.dot(W).dot(X_b)).dot(X_b.T).dot(W).dot(Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a diagonal matrix for `W`.

```
import numpy as np

sigma = # array of [nx1] sigmas
W = np.zeros((len(sigma), len(sigma)) # nxn matrix containing zeros
np.fill_diagonal(W, sigma)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html

Comment: Or ``W=np.diag(sigma)``. But your code, as my shorter version of it, just create a matrix whose diagonal is σₖ. What the OP wanted is one whose diagonal is 1/σₖ², So ``W=np.diag(1/sigma**2)`` more realisticly.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing, and indeed I called the array `sigma` but it can also be `weight` in which case the user should think about how to define the weights. But `np.diag` is indeed easier to use, I was under the assumption that `np.diag` only returned the diagonal, but this is easier and uses less steps than "my" method.

Comment: ``np.diag`` does both (both what you thought it did, and what I used it for here). ``np.diag([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`` is ``[1,5,9]``. ``np.diag([1,5,9])`` is ``[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]``. So, you could even say ``np.diag(np.diag(np.diag(W)))``, or any odd number of np.diag nested calls :). (An even number would be void: ``np.diag(np.diag(W))`` is ``W``)